# Issue with handling ePub pagination using Javascript with UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, uiwebview

I implemented a "mini epub reader" in my app.  In order to determine how many pages are in a chapter (based on pagination for the underlying `UIWebView` frame width), I get the scrollWidth via

`document.documentElement.scrollWidth`

and using the CSS style

`-webkit-column-width:` (`UIWebView`'s frame width).

and divide it by the `UIWebView`'s frame width.  So basically my "get next/previous page" uses the following Javascript

`window.scrollTo()`

Works fine except when the text fills up basically one viewable page exactly.  In that case, it seems the `document.documentElement.scrollWidth` is one page (`UIWebView` width) larger than necessary, and what I see are blank pages at the end of a chapter.

Any ideas how to avoid this, or somehow detect "blank" content in the viewable area?

BTW, this is when I'm handling ePub files with Japanese tategaki, so in reality I'm using

`document.documentElement.scrollHeight`

but the idea should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it was the margins causing the blanks.  This CSS did the trick

```
 margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; margin-top: 0%; margin-bottom: 0%;
```

Comment: In CSS you can always just say 0 instead of 0% or 0px as they all result in 0. Also you can use the shorthand margin: 0;

Comment: I'm currently (as of iOS8) having problems calculating the number of pages in a similar setup. What element did you apply this CSS to?